# Automounting encrypted SD card on boot/login

Tags: mount, encryption, automount, sd-card, luks

I'm looking to encrypt my SD card so that if it gets swiped out of my laptop the data won't be accessible. I want it to automount either on system start or on user login (I'm the only user). PW or keyfiles, I don't mind which, as long as there's no additional input needed from me. I'm aiming more for convenience than security, in terms of security it's purely for if it gets swiped, the laptop itself is secure enough that it's unlikely anyone would gain access through that.

I've tried with the disks utility and Veracrypt and neither seem to support it. I'd prefer to do it natively in Linux but if third party software is the only option (or is significantly simpler than doing it natively) then that's fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Disclaimer: As you pointed out already, this method is unsafe...*

Best would be to add your mount to the **Favorites** in Veracrypt. To do that, just mount the file/device in Veracrypt then rightclick and select "**Add to Favorites..**"

Then you can simply mount it from the commandline with

```
veracrypt --auto-mount=favorites -p YOURPASSWORD
```

To do that on start of your session, use **Startup Applications** and enter the command, like this

[image]

---

**Safer option**

Don't pass the PW via the commandline, this can be easily read or intercepted. Better to enter the PW after boot, simply omit the PW from the command and Veracrypt will prompt you for it

```
veracrypt --auto-mount=favorites
```

will give you this dialog

[image]

Comment: Great, this is almost exactly what I was looking for! I've gone with the less secure option obviously due to the reasons above. The only extra added work here is that it does ask me for my admin password again on login so as to grant Veracrypt the necessary permissions, but I can live with that